# Grease pencil 2.8 stroke placement problem

Tags: grease-pencil, axis

i'm currently working on blender 2.8, and i'm importing some mixamo models for drawing over them, my problem is when i draw strokes that if i move the view: the strokes move too like a 3d object, on 2.8: **stroke placement panel** : there's no more **"view"** as a possible choice but "origin", anybody has an idea on how to configure "stroke placement" in a way that **the strokes doesn't move when i move the view port on different axis**? Thanks!

stroke placement "view" in 2.79 blender ver.[image: stroke placement "view" in 2.79 blender ver.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just finded a workaround.

Go to Layers of Grease Pencil, and under the Relations drop menu you have to Parent the Layer to the Camera.

To predict better the draw radius I set up the grease pencil to draw with 3D Cursor and in Side (Y-Z) or Front (it depends). Remember that you have to place the cursor closer to the camera so it overlaps any other model in the scene.
[image: stroke placement View workaround]